# Achieving numpy like fast interpolation in Fortran

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, interpolation

I have a numerical routine that I need to run to solve a certain equation, which contains a few nested four loops. I initially wrote this routine into Python, using numba.jit to achieve an acceptable performance. For large system sizes however, this method becomes quite slow, so I have been rewriting the routine into Fortran hoping to achieve a speed-up. However I have found that my Fortran version is much slower than the first version in Python, by a factor of 2-3.

I believe the bottleneck is a linear interpolation function that is called at each innermost loop. In the Python implementation I use `numpy.interp`, which seems to be pretty fast when combined with `numba.jit`. In Fortran I wrote my own interpolation function, which reads,

```
  complex*16 function interp(x_dat, y_dat, N_dat, x)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: N_dat
    real*8, dimension(N_dat), intent(in) :: x_dat
    complex*16, dimension(N_dat), intent(in) :: y_dat
    real*8, intent(in) :: x

    complex*16 :: y, y1, y2
    integer :: i, i1, i2, im

    if(x <= x_dat(1)) then
      y = y_dat(1)
    else if(x >= x_dat(N_dat)) then
      y = y_dat(N_dat)
    else
      im = MINLOC(DABS(x_dat - x), DIM=1)
      if(x_dat(im) >=x ) then
        i1 = im
        i2 = im - 1
      else
        i1 = im + 1
        i2 = im
      end if

      y1 = y_dat(i1)
      y2 = y_dat(i2)

      y = y1 + (x-x_dat(i1))*(y2 - y1)/(x_dat(i2) - x_dat(i1))
    end if
    interp = y
    return
  end function interp
```

Note that I need to interpolate complex data. If my diagnostics are correct this function is much slower than `numpy.interp`, which, since the interpolation has to be called in each loop, greatly reduces the speed of the whole program.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve Numpy like interpolation speeds in Fortran? Or if my interpolation function as shown above here is somehow horribly inefficient? I don't have much experience coding Fortran yet.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Have you profiled this so you know which line(s) are taking the most time? 2) How big is n_dat? 3) Is x_dat sorted? 4) Can you please, provide a complete program, without that it is much more difficult to say anything 5) Note `DABS` should not have been used since 1977, use `ABS` 6) Note complex*16 is not standard Fortran, and has never been standard Fortran  - learn about kinds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter to do it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess (and see @IanBush's comments if you want to enable us to do better than guessing), it's the line

```
im = MINLOC(DABS(x_dat - x), DIM=1)
```

which is taking all your time, as this line is `O(N)` in the size of `x_dat`, where everything else is `O(1)`.

If `x_dat` is linearly spaced then you can replace this line with

```
im = 1 + nint((N_dat-1)*(x-x_dat(1))/(x_dat(N_dat)-x_dat(1)))
```

or better yet, skip `im` entirely and calculate `i1` and `i2` as

```
i1 = 1 + floor((N_dat-1)*(x-x_dat(1))/(x_dat(N_dat)-x_dat(1)))
i2 = i1 + 1
```

If `x_dat` is not linearly spaced, but has other useful properties, then you want to use these properties to calculate `im` if possible.

Comment: My data is indeed linearly spaced, silly that I didn't think of this immediately. Thanks a bunch!